# how to calculate the minimum of two variables simply in bash?

Tags: bash, logical-operators

I have a bash script checking the number of CPUs on the platform to efficiently use `-j` option for make, repo, etc.  I use this:

```
JOBS=$(cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep processor | tail -1 | sed "s,^.*:.*\([0-9].*\)$,\1,")
echo -e "4\n$JOBS" | sort -r | tail -1
```

It works fine. But, I am wondering if there was any built-in function which does the same thing (i.e. calculating the minimum, or maximum)?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but what is your `cat` pipeline supposed to be doing? It seems like `grep ^processor /proc/cpuinfo | sed -n -e '$s/.*://p'` would be just as effective.

Comment: Another note in regard to your "how many cores" pipeline: Since you want to know how many cores are available in the system, you don't have to determine "what is the highest processor number", but actually a safer and simpler way would be to, well, *count* them: `grep ^processor /proc/cpuinfo | wc -l`.

Comment: What about just using `nproc` ?

Answer (score 148, accepted):

If you mean to get `MAX(4,$JOBS)`, use this:

```
echo $((JOBS>4 ? JOBS : 4))
```

Comment: I meant the min, but yes, thanks for your answer!
`echo $(($JOBS<4?$JOBS:4))`

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know `$(( ))` supported the ternary operator. Very useful. You can omit the `$`s inside it, if you want: `$((JOBS > 4 ? JOBS : 4))`

Comment: @Anonymous Bash doesn't support floats in any native way, so you'll have to either use non-portable solutions like `bc` or make some clever hacks like separating the int/decimal parts and comparing them separately.

Comment: I assume this solution is Bash native. Some expanding on why it works, or the meaning of the shell expansion (or whatever it is) would be great.

Comment: It’s a very simple example of what is often referred to as the “ternary operator”, present in a lot of programming languages, just google it.

Answer (score 34):

Had a similar situation where I had to find the minimum out of **several** variables, and a somewhat different solution I found useful was `sort`

```
#!/bin/bash

min_number() {
    printf "%s\n" "$@" | sort -g | head -n1
}

v1=3
v2=2
v3=5
v4=1

min="$(min_number $v1 $v2 $v3 $v4)"
```

I guess It's not the most efficient trick, but for a small constant number of variables, it shouldn't matter much - and it's more readable than nesting ternary operators.

---

**EDIT**: Referring Nick's great comment - this method can be expanded to any type of sort usage:

```
#!/bin/bash

min() {
    printf "%s\n" "${@:2}" | sort "$1" | head -n1
}
max() {
    # using sort's -r (reverse) option - using tail instead of head is also possible
    min ${1}r ${@:2}
}

min -g 3 2 5 1
max -g 1.5 5.2 2.5 1.2 5.7
min -h 25M 13G 99K 1098M
max -d "Lorem" "ipsum" "dolor" "sit" "amet"
min -M "OCT" "APR" "SEP" "FEB" "JUL"
```